# Can there be a non-trivial $A_\infty$-algebra which is Z/2-graded?

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, operads

I am not used to $A_\infty$-algebras, so I am sorry if this is a stupid question. It seems that an $A_\infty$-algebra $A$ is typically a $\mathbb Z$-graded vector space $A$ along with morphisms

$$ m_k: A^{\otimes k}\longrightarrow A$$

of degree $(2-k)$, satisfying some equations.

Because of the degree $(2-k)$, it is clear that if I want $A$ to be concentrated in degree $0$, then all $m_k=0$ for $k\ne 2$.

But what if I suppose that $A$ is $\mathbb Z/2$-graded instead of $\mathbb Z$-graded and $A$ is concentrated in degree $0$? In other words: $A=A_{\bar{0}}\oplus A_{\bar{1}}$ with $A_{\bar{1}}=0$.

In that case, since  $m_k:A^{\otimes k}\longrightarrow A$ has to have degree $(2-k)$, I think it means that $m_k=0$ when $k$ is odd.

So my definition would look like this: A $\mathbb Z/2$-graded $A_\infty$ algebra consists of a $\mathbb Z/2$-graded vector space $B=B_{\bar{0}}\oplus 
B_{\bar{1}}$ and morphisms

$$ m_k: B^{\otimes k}\longrightarrow B $$

of degree $(2-k)=k$ (mod $2$) and satisfying the usual conditions.

Now, I want to consider those $\mathbb Z/2$-graded $A_\infty$-algebras such that $B_{\bar{1}}=0$. In that case, $m_k=0$ whenever $k$ is odd.

Does this make sense or have I reached something trivial? Are there examples of this? Any reference or pointers would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: This should be the same as a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded $A_\infty$-Algebra over the base $\mathbb{Z}[b^{\pm 1}]$, with $b$ of degree $2$. There should be many nonequivalent such things with the same $A_0$. (I.e. I think the literal answer to your question is "yes, this makes sense and your observations are correct")

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please elaborate a little? I didn't really understand because I have just started reading on this topic. Are there any links or references?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you really mean with $\mathbb Z/2$-graded. It seems like Achim used the usual interpretation in his comment; but that does not seem (at least at first sight) to be the same thing as what you wrote, namely what you wrote is what people would call "concentrated in degrees $0$ and $1$", rather than $\mathbb Z/2$-graded. It would be nice to clarify that I think

Comment: I think the post clearly refers to a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-graded object concentrated in degree $0$, and not a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded object in degrees $0,1$. Reread the third- and second-to-last paragraph

Comment: Hi, sorry about the confusion. I have edited the question and hopefully it is clear now. All comments welcome.

Comment: @AchimKrause : yes, you're absolutely right, I had misread; thanks !